# How to configure 403 template in bjyauthorize

Tags: zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I just setup the [`bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/) and wonder how I can tell Zend Framework 2 where my `error/403` template lies.

I didn't configure the initial setting of `'template' => 'error/403',`

The `403.phtml` file lies within the vendor directory but I get the following error message:

> **Warning**: include(C:\myproject\config\autoload/../view/error/403.phtml) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php on line 507

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: I am not sure what your plan is , AFAIK , you can't use composer for bjyauthorize and also , you need to put it in modules directory and just add it in your global configuration modules list . I think php renderer is not accessible inside vendor directory in your case , so you have to do a work around to achieve this

Comment: Also Here is the example application which has all required modules which are well configured . https://github.com/patrioticcow/Zend-Project its really good to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance reasons (mainly avoiding stat calls), [BjyAuthorize uses the template map](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/1.2.1/config/module.config.php#L59-L65) to define which file to use when the `error/403` view is requested. This is an option of the `view_manager` settings, as described in the [`Zend\View` documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration).

To set your own, you can simply define something like following in your `config/autoload/your-settings.local.php`:

```php
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'error/403' => '/absolute/path/to/your/error/403.phtml',
    ),
),
```

Or, in your module config:

```php
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'error/403' => __DIR__ . '/view/error/403.phtml',
    ),
),
```

I suggest always providing absolute paths for configuration, so be sure that your file `C:\myproject\config\autoload/../view/error/403.phtml` is the correct path.

You can also use a different view for 403 errors if you prefer to do so. That can be achieved by changing `$config['bjyauthorize']['template']`:

```php
'bjyauthorize' => array(
    'template' => 'my-module/unauthorized-template',
),
```

Comment: And again a stupid one! I overlooked that the path to my template was defined in the 'module.bjyauthorize.global.php'. I altered the path in the view_manager there and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set:

```
'error/403' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/403.phtml',
```

in module/Application/config/module.config.php and comment out this line in module.bjyauthorize.global.php. I'm assuming you are working with the skeleton.

@aravind.udayashankara, BjyAuthorize does work with composer and the skeleton already comes configured to load modules in the vendor as well, so no need to move it in modules directory.

However, it does seem that phprender isn't able to access the view directory in the vendor. It might be the way "error/403' => **DIR** . '/../view/error/403.phtml" is actually mapped/interpreted at runtime.